# Proving that an exponential inequality is true/false

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For which nonnegative $n$ is $3^n>n^3$ true?

I considered the four first cases:
$$3^0=1>0$$
$$3^1=3>1^3$$
$$3^2=9>2^3$$
$$3^3=27\ngtr3^3$$

I want to show that $\forall n\ge3,\;3^n>n^3$ is false.

Considering the base case $n=3$:
$$3^3=27\ngtr3^3.$$
For values greater than $3$, this can be done by using the limit:

$$\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}3^n>\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}n^3$$
since $3^n$ in an exponential function, it grows faster than the cubic function, and since we have shown that the recursion is true $\forall n<3$, we have proven that $3^n>n^3$ is false $\forall \: n\ge3$.

But I am not sure whether using the limit is a valid proof?

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: "We have proven that $3^n>n^3$ is invalid for all $n\ge 3$" ?? No, take $3^4=81>64=4^3$.

Comment: That is a calculation, not a proof?

Comment: Yes, but one calculation is enough to disprove your statement. And I could add another one: $3^5=243>125=5^3$

Comment: It is not valid. Both limits are undefined.

Comment: @DietrichBurde suprised!! What can be done here?

Comment: Just do a few examples and then prove the general case for $n\ge 4$. $3^n$ grows much faster.

Comment: Thanks , so we can assume that anything greater  than 4 gives validity for that?

Comment: Remember that *any* exponential will grow faster than *any* polynomial. So for $[\forall k \exists N](\forall n \ge N \mid k^n > n^k)$ Then it remains to find an intersection or lower bound for any given $n$, which you did for $3$, and to check lower values. $3$ is actually a special case: it's the only $k$ for which there are *no* integers $n$ where $k^n < n^k$.

Comment: @EricSnyder So the limit method was sufficient?

Comment: Yes, but you drew the wrong conclusion; $3^n > n^3$ is *true* for $n \ne 3$, not false as you say at the bottom.

Comment: @EricSnyder great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use induction. The result is true for any $n>3$. Base case $n=4$, which satisfies $3^4=81>64=4^3$. Now suppose that for some $k$ we have $3^k>k^3 \implies 3^{k+1}>3k^3$

We need $3^{k+1}>(k+1)^3 $

So, its enough to prove $3k^3>(k+1)^3\iff \left(1+\frac1k\right)^3<3$

For $k=3,\left(1+\frac1k\right)^3=\frac{64}{27}<3$

and $\left(1+\frac1{k+1}\right)^3<\left(1+\frac1k\right)^3$

$\implies \left(1+\frac1k\right)^3<3$ for $k\ge3$

Comment: Based on this, what is the range of $n$ for which the inequality is invalid? (Since n=4 > n=3)

Comment: $n=1, 2$ and for $n>3$. For $n=3$ we have strict equality